# IEnumerable<Process> Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, process, ienumerable

in this code trying to fetch a process by name 
how can i add a second filter to query

```
      IEnumerable<Process> processList =

                from p in Process.GetProcesses()
                where p.ProcessName.StartsWith("Mon") || p.ProcessName.StartsWith("Tue")
                select p;
```

it is what i tried corrected it , the example above dows work

Comment: You mean you want to add more to you where clause? Just use && or || and keep adding conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<Process> processList = from p in Process.GetProcesses()
                where p.ProcessName.StartsWith("Mon") && p.Property == somethingElse && ...
                select p;
```

just add && if you want AND conditions or || if you want OR conditions.

edit after OP commented:

If you want to access the elements of your IEnumerable:

```
var element1 = processList.ElementAt(0);
```

if you want to iterate over all the elements, you can use a foreach.

```
     foreach (var i in processList)
    {
    Response.Write(i.ProcessName);
    //or if you're using a console application: Console.WriteLine(i.ProcessName);
    }
```

Comment: what is ToList() & why did you use it or where should we. the IEnumerable isn't allready something we can use?

Comment: i thought you had List<Process> instead of IEnumerable, which would need a .ToList() at the end of your query to compile at all.

Comment: @Jand Doe how would you access first 'cell' in an `IEnumerable`, in a normal array : `MyArray[0]` and  here if i would like to avoid foreach how would it be possible to access p.name id ...

Comment: first cell? you mean the first element of the list?

Comment: i editted my answer, altho i dont understand why you want to avoid using a foreach. i guess to answer your question, to get elements of an IEnumerable, you use .ElementAt(index) instead of using indexer brackets [] like with arrays

Comment: stopwatched for each and it is x10 one loop and x80 slower to fetch the both of processes needd , x80 i guess is for not breaking *that's where it finished looping , but for ten times slower then not foreaching and extracting the p.id /name / handle by assigning it straight into a variable i was comparing it to the time it took to Enumerate

Comment: i dont quite understand what you're saying, is your problem solved now or are you asking something different now?

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<Process> processList =
    from p in Process.GetProcesses()
    where p.ProcessName.StartsWith("Mon")
    where p.ProcessName.EndsWith("day")
    select p;
```

Comment: thanks, i tried use: where () || () .  instead where () || where ()

Answer (score 0):

My answer is after OP's correction of question to demonstrate Extension methods

```
IEnumerable<Process> processes = 
Process.GetProcesses()
.Where(p => p.ProcessName.StartsWith("Mon") || p.ProcessName.EndsWith("Tue"));
```